# Как я могу переменную в java вернуть из одной функции и вставить её в другую?

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public static String executePost(String urlParameters) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            //Create connection
            URL url = new URL("https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/pubinfo?json&exchange&coursid=5");
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length",
                    Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");

            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);

            //Send request
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream (
                    connection.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
            wr.close();

            //Get Response
            InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder(); // or StringBuffer if Java version 5+
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
                response.append('\r');
            }
            rd.close();
            String resp = response.toString();
            return resp;
            //return response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

    }
    public void onButtonClick (View  v String resp) {
        TextView rateText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
        rateText.setText(resp);
    }
}
```

Как мне переменную resp вставить в функцию onButtonClick()
потому-что данный код выдает ошибку . Я с java знаком 2 дня, перешел с Python. Если что-то делаю не так или нужен другой подход, то пожалуйста укажите как что делать.

Comment: `rateText.setText(MainActivity.executePost("parameter"));

Comment: ява в этом отношении ничем не отличается от питона. А ошибки надо читать

Answer (score 0):

Для начала нужно понять, что у вас статический метод. Такие методы не имеют доступа ко внутренним переменным класса.

Вам нужно создать переменную:

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String response;
```

Затем, переменную нужно заполнить данными. ***Не забудьте! Работа с сетью в основном потоке (UI потоке) вызовет исключение!*** Для этого нужно вызвать метод:

```java
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        AsyncTask.execute(() -> {
            String res = executePost(params);
            mButton.post(() -> {
                response = res;
            });
        });
    }
```

Теперь ваша переменная будет заполнена данными, но не сразу. Для того, чтобы узнать, когда она заполнится, лучше заблокировать кнопку в `execute` методе, а в `post` разблокировать.

Подробнее можете почитать [тут](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) или [тут](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/asynctask.php).